# ternary operator on linear search in javascript now working

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, ternary, linear-search

so, i have the linear search implemented in JS and i tried to implement it with ternary operator but the it returns -1...

I have this code:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function linear(arr, value) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        return (arr[i] === value ? i : -1);
    }
}
```

when I run `console.log(linear(numbers, 3))`, it gives me -1 as a result, and 3 is in my array. Anyone ?

Also, when i try with forEach it returns undefined code here:

```
function linearSearch(arr, value) {
    arr.forEach((num, index) => {
        return (num === value ? index : -1);
    })
}

const res = linearSearch(numbers, 3);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: That's what `return` does, it breaks the execution of the current function immediately and returns a value to the caller. In your case, the loop is always broken on the first index.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning at the first loop of your circle,
you should change your algorithm like this:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function linear(arr, value) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === value) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(linear(numbers, 3));
```

However, if you don't need an explicit implementation of the algorithm, a much cleaner version of this would be by using the built-in `indexOf` function:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(numbers.indexOf(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you return too often. Meaning, you never get further than your first iteration, because then you either return 0 (if the first element matches) or -1 if it doesn't. Here's a proposed fix:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function linear(arr, value) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if(arr[i] === value) {
      return i
    }
  }
  return -1
}
```

In the second example, you do the same thing, but in addition to this, it seems you don't fully understand how the callback in `.forEach(callback)` works (meaning that if you return something inside a `.forEach`, nothing happens to that returned value). I don't think a `.forEach` is the way to go here, but if you really wish to use it, you could do it like so:

```js
function linear2(arr, value) {
  let indexMatch = -1
  arr.forEach((num, index) => {
    if(value === num) {
      indexMatch = index
    }
  }
  return indexMatch 
}
```